# How to go to a specific column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

My requirement is simple...

I have a table in SQL with more than 300 columns in it and I need to compare the data present in those columns with the source table.

Now every time I cannot waste my time finding where is the column I want to compare the data by dragging.

So my question is...Is there any short cut or code to go to a specific column when in case of a large table as in my requirement.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: An example of 'what you exactly want' would help us to understand

Comment: Lets say I have 300 columns in employee table and I have run the query select * from employee and in the query result I get the o/p..now I need to check the data populated in emp_address and I don't know where that column is exactly..so manually I need to drag the bar searching the column..so I want to know is there any short cut where I can directly reach the specific column which I want to check

Comment: are you using SQLDevolper? Are u comparing manually or with some code? you can select the required columns like `select col1,col2,col3... from employee` instead of `*`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: If "source" and "actual" tables have **identical** structure use: `select * from source_table except select * from some_table`

Comment: My data base is oracle and no my tables structures are not similar and yes I am using SQL developer...

Comment: This requirement is actually from Informatica where I map source columns to target after applying the business logic and in the back end that is in SQL developer I need to compare and validate the data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My question was with respect to the output we get after we run the query!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to compare two tables based on the requirement.

If your source can be accessible for you then simple MINUS will do.

```
In Oracle:

SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3.... FROM SOURCE
MINUS
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3.... FROM TARGET
```

In Informatica you can generate MD5 hash for the column you want to compare from both Source and Target and check whether both hashes are matching.